# Angularjs $http.post and $http.get empty response from API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I'm trying to get some information from an API, but em I run this code bellow I get nothing.
 On firefox console :

[image]

```
app.controller('Test', function($scope, $http) {

    $http.post("http://api.olhovivo.sptrans.com.br/v0/Login/Autenticar?token=fde20482b4aecc6334096c63a39d714a0ca379dd7ab599c4312c93161ce17781").success(function(data) {
        $scope.token = "Oi"; 
    });

    $http.get("http://api.olhovivo.sptrans.com.br/v0/Linha/Buscar?termosBusca=9").then(function(response) {

            $scope.token = response;
        });     

 // http://api.olhovivo.sptrans.com.br/v0/Login/Autenticar?token=fde20482b4aecc6334096c63a39d714a0ca379dd7ab599c4312c93161ce17781


}).config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {

        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Length']= "0";


    }]);
```

if just paste and go the same URL(http://api.olhovivo.sptrans.com.br/v0/Linha/Buscar?termosBusca=9) on my browser after I run that code, it does return all the json data I need

Thanks

Comment: `$scope.token = respose;` Typo?

Comment: Yes, sorry, just fixed that(the typo no the problem)

Comment: Are you sure you are not running into a CORS issue? You would want to check your console to see if it shows a "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" message there.

Comment: Yeh, that's what is happing, I'm trying to figure out how to fix this as it's nota server under my control... thx